# How to capture all Error messages from Python and save them in a txt file

Tags: python, file, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I would like to capture all errors that are created during the runtime or during testing(using pytest) of a Python program. So far I have managed to capture all output of pytest using a plugin for pytest which saves the output to a .txt file line by line.

But now I would like to have all the errors created by Python in a .txt file.  As I am new to Python and also new to such capturing of program output, do you have any ideas how could I achieve something like this?

Thanks for all the answers in advance.

EDIT: I am creating a plugin for PyCharm IDE, which could visualize these Errors in a certain way, that is why I need those errors saved somewhere, so I can work with them later during the visualization. If there is a better way to save them, please share it.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Your application already has testing in it that drops a text file but you want more information inside your text file? Are you wanting to collect all the data the is put in the text files and upload it to a single source so you as the developer can view what errors are occurring in the field?

Just for future reference: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking another question

Comment: Addedthe reason for the saving in the question, thanks for correcting me.